# Angular Material and materialize css together

Tags: css, angular-material

I was using angular material but it does not have the full angular material css classes . So I tried adding materialize css to index.html but now I am getting 2 css styles one from angular materialize theme and other from the materialize css which I added to index.html

Is there any way by which I can add add materialize css without breaking a angular-material theme

Comment: Use only relevant styles inside your angular component and not just copy paste the whole bunch of it and make use of `!important` if you want to force some of your own styles over the theme. But copy pasting just the missing styles will definitely collide with your theme design.

Comment: Yeah so whats happening right now there is two style applied on textboxes as both materialize.css and angular-material indigo pink theme clash with each other

Comment: then only use the one and that you need and go to the theme styles search for the same class and remove it or if you want to keep it then just use yours but make use `!important` in your css styles to force them upon your textboxes in this way it will use only one design

Comment: They are not meant to be used together. Angular Material is a Material Design component library for the Angular framework which includes its own theme and styling. Materialize CSS is a Material Design CSS class and JavaScript library for HTML. Both will apply style to various elements and have no way of cooperating with each other. You _might_ be able to apply _some_ Materialize CSS classes to elements as long as they are not part of Angular Material components and as long as there are no globally applied styles that could affect Angular Material components.

Comment: so is angular material limited to what it is shown in the angularmaterial website ? or does it have all functionalities of material css